# Simple buttons and Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have some buttons and a message displaying depending on the user choice, right now only "correct" shows no matter the choice, what's wrong with my code?:

**HTML:**

```
  <button id = "dec12" onclick="clickF1()"> December 12 <br> 2014 </button>
  <button id = "nov13" onclick="clickF1()"> November 13 <br> 2014 </button>
  <button id = "dec15" onclick="clickF1()"> December 15 <br> 2014 </button>

  <h2 id ="output1"></h2>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function clickF1() {

var dec12 = document.getElementById("dec12");
var nov13 = document.getElementById("nov13");
var dec15 = document.getElementById("dec15");

if ("dec12") {
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Correct!";

} else if ("nov13") {
   document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Way off!";

} else if ("dec15") {
   document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Close but nope!";

 }
}
```

Comment: `if ("dec12") ` ... a string is "truthy" - so that's always true

Comment: Because id exist every time, you create it when u enter function

Comment: But it doesn't work if i do if (dec12) either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements are *always* true, because a literal string always exists.  (It is always "truthy" in JavaScript.)  Even if you remove the quotes and just check the variables, they'd still *always* be true because those variables always exist.

It sounds like you just want to know which element was clicked.  Have the element pass an identifier into the function.  Something like this:

```
<button id = "dec12" onclick="clickF1('dec12')"> December 12 <br> 2014 </button>
<button id = "nov13" onclick="clickF1('nov13')"> November 13 <br> 2014 </button>
<button id = "dec15" onclick="clickF1('dec15')"> December 15 <br> 2014 </button>
```

Then check that value in the function:

```
function clickF1(day) {

  if (day == "dec12") {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Correct!";
  } else if (day == "nov13") {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Way off!";
  } else if (day == "dec15") {
    document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Close but nope!";
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `clickF1` function is always running the same code. You should separate buttons by passing some variable when clicked.

For example, You can pass button, and then analyze it's id, like this:

**HTML:**

```
  <button id = "dec12" onclick="clickF1(this)"> December 12 <br> 2014 </button>
  <button id = "nov13" onclick="clickF1(this)"> November 13 <br> 2014 </button>
  <button id = "dec15" onclick="clickF1(this)"> December 15 <br> 2014 </button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function clickF1(button) {
    var id = button.id;

if (id == "dec12") {
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Correct!";

} else if (id == "nov13") {
   document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Way off!";

} else if (id == "dec15") {
   document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = "Close but nope!";

 }
}
```